# How do I call an oracle stored procedure using jstl in my web project?

Tags: java, oracle, web, jstl, procedure

All the inserts, updates and deletes need to be implemented in my database i need to know a form of calling them from my web application using jstl.
 I'll appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

It is possible
See http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2008/04/call-stored-procedure-from-jsp-with.html
but change **exec** with **call**

Answer (score 0):

You must not do that. Come up with a DAO layer which does the database stuff and use your DAO in your controller / servlet. Never ever should you invoke database code directly from JSP!

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do it please?